# How to avoid both elements from showing for a split second with ng-hide and ng-show in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have page with two different selects, one shows times that a venue is open in the AM, the other shows times it is open in the PM.  I am using an ng-hide and ng-show on the value of a different select to decide which select to show.  It works ok, but for a split second it shows both selects on the page, is there anyway to avoid this?
My code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
      <label class="control-label">Time</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="referral.reservationTime" ng-show="referral.reservationTimeAmOrPm === 'AM'">
        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select a Time</option>
        <option ng-repeat="hour in amHours">{{hour | militaryToStandardTimeNoAmOrPm}}</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="referral.reservationTime" ng-hide="referral.reservationTimeAmOrPm === 'AM'">
        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select a Time</option>
        <option ng-repeat="hour in pmHours">{{hour | militaryToStandardTimeNoAmOrPm}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try `ng-cloak`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: That didn't work, I assume thats because ngCloak is used to hide elements in theri non-compiled state while the page is loading, in my case the elements are in their compiled state already I am just trying to hide one and show anther at the same time.

Comment: What if you leave just a single block here, but will switch between `amHours` and `pmHours` depending on the attribute's value?